# Comments defined in typedef not appearing in Apollo Server 2.0 Playground UI

Tags: apollo-server

A descriptive comment I write in the typedef file does not seem to be appearing in the Apollo Server 2.0 Playground UI. Here is the screenshot

[image: Screen shot of UI without comment]

I am creating the typedef file in NodeJS using the `gql` module, like so:

`const { gql } = require('apollo-server');`

```
    # Describes an album released by either a band or musician
    type Album {
        id: String
        title: String
        releaseDate: String
        songs: [Song]
        musician: Musician
        band: Band
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2):

A colleague suggested this, using 3 quotes. It works at the start of a type def:

```
"""
musicians describes the composer(s) of the song
"""
```

Comment: This worked for me with Next.JS and apollo-server-micro